# How change build options in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, build

I have a project in netbeans in which I have a java scanner which has been generated using jflex. So when I usually build this using a make file I use the -Xlint option, that is

```
javac -Xlint javaScanner.java
```

But now when I am creating the jar file using the clean and build option it is showing the following error.

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build
Updating property file: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/classes
Created dir: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/empty
Created dir: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 35 source files to /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 1 file to /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/dist
Copying 1 file to /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/build
Copy libraries to /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/dist/lib.
Building jar: /home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/dist/sDvait-LCS.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "/home/mridula/testPrjct/sDvait-LCS/dist/sDvait-LCS.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

If I could know how the file is being built. I could just add the -Xlint option so that the jar file could be created without a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Netbeans uses ant to build java projects. There is a *build.xml* file in your project dir that handles this process.

But you have another option:

Right click your project node, choose "Properties" (a dialog box pops up). On the left choose "Compiling" and add your options in the field "Additional compiler options"

Comment: Yes I did see that. But what I am asking is - There are lot of java files that I have in my project. I want to compile a particular java file 'javaScanner.java' with the option -Xlint. I could not find an option to do it by right clicking and the build.xml also did not make much sense. Could I do it like compile the particular java file separately with the build option and put it in the desired location in the jar file. I am not sure of this.

Comment: The _build.xml_ (or for Netbeans projects the imported _build-impl.xml_) manages the build process. It would be the right place to do this. I don't know any other option.

Comment: You can add any build target you want to your build scripts.  If you want to compile only one file, add a target that does so.  There is also an option in the _Build_ menu to compile the current file.