# Variable information is not available, source compiled without -g option

Tags: java, netbeans

When I was debugging my project , I have no idea why I cant see the values of my variable

[image]

It seems I am compiling without the -g option .

How do i compile with the -g option ??

Comment: Can you try to initialize your variable? change that to int value=0; and Try again.

Comment: @Payam Makes no difference

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883918/how-change-build-options-in-netbeans, add "-g" to "Additional compiler options"